# Power Analysis in Xlinx ISE

Tags: xilinx

I wanted to know the performance of the design in terms of switching activity (hence the power consumption) using Xlinx ISE.

I have Xlinx ISE 14.3 webpack version.

Is it possible to do such analysis? If so how do it? I'm novice in using Xlinx ISE, just have started to understand different options made available in the tool.

One more point to add, the synthesis stage of the design fails due to license issue! Does it affect in doing power analysis?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for power consumption, the easiest way to measure it is to load your design onto an FPGA, connect it to a power supply through a multimeter, and take note of the power. If you're trying to measure very small currents, you may need to use more precise equipment.